# Sharing clickable image

Tags: android, facebook, uri

I am working on an Android app and would like to allow the user to share a screenshot of their progress, which I will generate dynamically, but I would like it if friends clicking on the image in Facebook will be taken to my app install page.  I know I can statically link to my app install page but I need to post the screenshot because the user's motivation is to ask their friends to help with the game progress.  Right now I'm using the following code to post the image:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    Uri img = Uri.fromFile(picture); // Supplied by the caller.

    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, img);
    // Include your Facebook App Id for attribution
    intent.putExtra("com.facebook.platform.extra.APPLICATION_ID", appID);

    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, caption), SHARE_REQUEST);
```

Is there a way to make it so that FB users clicking on the image will be taken to the app page?  If at all possible I'd prefer to do this through the Android API because it gives you the option of sharing to multiple locations.

Thank you.

Comment: If you use Facebook ShareDialog, then you can just add link that you want to be opened.

Comment: Thank you Mike Clark.  Do you know if there's a way to do this through the Android API?  I would prefer that if possible because it gives the user the option to post to several social network sites, not just Facebook.